# "snake" in html5 canvas. Math curve issue

Tags: html, canvas, curve

[Demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4552022/CanvasCurve/index.html)

I am trying to make a "snake" game in html 5 canvas. But i have a problem getting the snake to move the right direction. I would assume that the following code would make the snake move horizontal on 0 and 180 degrees, and vertical on 90 and 270 degrees, this is however not the case. What am i doing wrong here? (Use the left and right arrows to navigate).

```
function move(direction) {
    if(direction == left) {
         angel = (angel - 5) % 360;
        if(angel < 0) angel += 360;
    } else if (direction == right) {
        angel = (angel + 5) % 360;
    }
    x = x + Math.floor(Math.cos(angel*0.0174532925)*5);
    y = y + Math.floor(Math.sin(angel*0.0174532925)*5);

    $("#infoBar").html("Direction: " + direction +  " angel: " + angel);

    drawPoint(x,y);
}
```

The multiplier is of course degrees to radiant. But somehow 270 degrees is not a straight vertical line, as i would assumed that it was. What am i doing wrong?

[Javascript file.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4552022/CanvasCurve/curve.js)

[Html file.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4552022/CanvasCurve/index.html)

Comment: seems overly complicated, if you only care about moving it up/down or left/right there's no need for calculating angles. Another thing i notice is that the angle variable is changing because it is being re-assigned to itself. Is that the intention?

Comment: i only intend to use the left/right arrows, since it is going forward by itself. and yes, the x,y is supposed to change since its the new "head" of the snake.

Comment: yes ok. Can you do something like this:
switch(direction)
case left: x--; break;
case right: x++; break;
case up: y--; break;
case down: y++; break;

Comment: well, that is not exactly the functionality i am looking for. i want my snake to move all the time, and change direction if the left or right key is pressed and held down :>

Comment: BTW, it's spelled "angle"; an ["angel"](http://www.hitupmyspot.com/angels/0angels4.gif) is something entirely different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of floating point math.

cos(270 degrees) = 0

Buuuut:

`Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*270)` is not `0`. It is: `-1.836909530733566e-16`

In other words it is -0.000000000000000183, etc. Very close to zero, but slightly less than zero!

But you're using `Math.floor`, and `Math.floor` that number (or `Math.floor(-0.1)` for that matter) = -1.

You don't want that.

Use `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor`.

Here's a live example of it fixed for you: http://jsfiddle.net/UtPJz/3/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't compiled the code segment but you could do somehting like this:

```
function move(direction) {
    switch(direction)
    {
        case RIGHT:
            stepX = 1;
            stepY = 0;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            stepX = -1;
            stepY = 0;
            break;
        case UP:
            stepX = 0;
            stepY = -1;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            stepX = 0;
            stepY = 1;
            break;
    }

    x += stepX;
    y += stepY;
    drawPoint(x,y);
}
```